# Is it possible to take array inputs in module terminal list?

Tags: verilog

I want to create a 16X1 mux with 4X1 mux.So can I create a module for 16x1 mux in this form?
module 16X1 (OUT,I0[0:3],I1[0:3],I2[0:3],I3[0:3],S4,S3,S2,S1)

Comment: I read the question wrong: Yes you can but nobody (outside education assignments for student) writes standalone muxes. You would normally use an `if` or `case` or even simpler use an index: `assign i = vector[select];`

Comment: Yes,you are correct,I'm a student.

Comment: Dataflow modelling hasn't been done yet.
16x1 mux was tedious to write so I thought maybe put the concept of arrays to use.
Why do arrays have such limited use in verilog?

Comment: *"Why do arrays have such limited use in Verilog?"* I suggest you post a question about that because a comment is too short for the answer. Before you do: think about this: Verilog is a HARDWARE description language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as long as you use the I1[0:3], I2[0:3], I3[0:3], I4[0:3], in the correct order as will be specified or else you'll get wrong answer at the output.

Comment: No,I just checked in EDA and verilog apparently doesn't support arrays in port declaration.Only System verilog allows arrays apparently.